# Asp.net core: count hotel booking date

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there any way to count the day of booking? either using lambda or sqlite query thanks, can find the solution for a while thanks~

The bookingInput is from a webpage of booking which contains rooms, checkin and check out.

The below code is Create.cshtml.cs in Booking folder (created by scaffolding)

```
int count = bookingInput.CheckOut.DayOfWeek - booking.CheckIn.DayOfWeek;
booking.Cost =  count * theRoom.Price;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [TimeSpan.TotalDays Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totaldays?view=net-5.0) to get the number of days between two dates.

Check the following code:

```
        //get data from the Repository.
        var result = _repo.GetBookings().Select(c => new
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Name = c.Name,
            RoomNumner = c.RoomNumber,
            CheckIn = c.CheckIn,
            CheckOut = c.CheckOut,
            Days = (c.CheckOut - c.CheckIn).TotalDays,
            RoundDays = Math.Round((c.CheckOut - c.CheckIn).TotalDays)
        });
```

The result as below:

[image]

The test data in the Repository:

```
public interface IDataRepository
{
    List<BookingViewModel> GetBookings();
}
public class DataRepository : IDataRepository
{
    public List<BookingViewModel> GetBookings()
    {
        return new List<BookingViewModel>()
       {
           new BookingViewModel(){ Id=101, Name="David", RoomNumber=1001, CheckIn= new DateTime(2021,1,18,15,30,0), CheckOut=DateTime.Now },
           new BookingViewModel(){ Id=102, Name="Jack", RoomNumber=2001, CheckIn= new DateTime(2021,1,15,10,30,0), CheckOut=DateTime.Now },
           new BookingViewModel(){ Id=103, Name="Tom", RoomNumber=3001, CheckIn= new DateTime(2021,1,20,18,30,0), CheckOut=DateTime.Now },
       };
    }
}
```

Comment: Look too advance for me, but thanks I will try.